# Proving uniform continuity given infinite limits and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=l\in\mathbb{R}$

$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=l'\in\mathbb{R}$

We want to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$

By the definition of limits:

$\exists\space M>0$ such that $\forall\space x>M$, $|f(x)-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

$\exists\space M'>0$ such that $\forall\space x<-M'$, $|f(x)-l'|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Let $M_{0}=\max\{M,M'\}$

Consider the interval $[-M_{0},M_{0}]$

Since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $[-M_{0},M_{0}]$

Now consider the interval $[M_{0},+\infty)$

Let $x,y\in[{M_{0},+\infty)}$, then actually $\forall\space\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$, we have:

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-l+l-f(y)|\le|f(x)-l|+|f(y)-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

This is true because we are working in the interval where $f$ is already converging to $l$.

So $f$ is uniformly continous on $[M_{0},+\infty)$ and since $M_{0}\in[-M_{0},M_{0}]$ and $M_{0}\in[M_{0},+\infty)$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[-M_{0},+\infty)$

Now consider the interval $(-\infty,-M_{0}]$

Let $x,y\in(-\infty,-M_{0}]$, then $\forall\space\delta'>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta'$, we have:

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-l'+l'-f(y)|\le|f(x)-l'|+|f(y)-l'|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

This is true because we are working in the inteval where $f$ is already converging to $l'$.

So $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,-M_{0}]$ and since $-M_{0}\in[-M_{0},+\infty)$ and $-M_{0}\in(-\infty,-M_{0}]$, then $f$ is uniformly continous on $\mathbb{R}$

I showed my professor this proof and he said that there is an error in logic. But he wants me to find out what it is, I can't seem to locate it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You cannot say "$\forall\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$, we have ...", because the definition of continuity says that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\underline{\text{there exists}}$ $\delta>0$..

Comment: @Redeldio, I understand but in this specific case, it works for all $\delta>0$ by virtue of it being in the zone where $f$ is converging. I could've said there exists (which is true) but it's also true that it works for all $\delta>0$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but, in my opinion, the error in logic that your professor noted is the use of the quantifiers. It is true that the inequality holds for all $\delta$ but, anyway, you have to say that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$. Then, the $\delta$ that allows the inequality hold is any number...

Comment: @Redeldio, alright I see!